# Javascript: Fire onChange by setting a value programatically

Tags: javascript, dojo

I know that an onChange event will fire if the value of a field is changed, so is it possible to fire the onChange via Chrome console by setting the property of a field programatically?

The field in question is an input field, with an onChange attached to update a div with its new value.

The problem is the onChange callback method is firing when it shouldn't be, and i need to test whether one of the set up methods is causing the callback to fire when it assigns the fields default value

Comment: might be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381407/fire-onchange-event-on-page-from-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this please:

```
<input id="numberBox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" /> 

<script>
    dojo.connect( dijit.byId('numberBox'), "onChange", function ( event ) { 
        dijit.byId('numberBox').set('value', 12345 );
    }); 

    dijit.byId('numberBox').onChange();
</script>
```